# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. Shared preferences package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error with `Shared Preferences`  package.
I'm using the last version of the package that supports null safety.

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Network {
  final String _url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
  var token;

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('access_token'));
    print(token.toString());
  }
```

I'm getting this error :

```
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it like this :

```
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('access_token') as String);
```